# NuiFusionCreateImageFrame causes 0xc000007b

Tags: windows, kinect

Now when i try to call NuiFusionCreateImageFrame, the application gets the 0xc000007b error.
if i comment this line, error is gone.

some code:

```
#define NOMINMAX
#include <Windows.h>

#include <Kinect.h>
#include <NuiKinectFusionApi.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"Kinect20.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"Kinect20.fusion.lib")

int main()
{
    NUI_FUSION_CAMERA_PARAMETERS cameraParameters;

    cameraParameters.focalLengthX = NUI_KINECT_DEPTH_NORM_FOCAL_LENGTH_X;
    cameraParameters.focalLengthY = NUI_KINECT_DEPTH_NORM_FOCAL_LENGTH_Y;
    cameraParameters.principalPointX = NUI_KINECT_DEPTH_NORM_PRINCIPAL_POINT_X;
    cameraParameters.principalPointY = NUI_KINECT_DEPTH_NORM_PRINCIPAL_POINT_Y;


    UINT width = 512, height = 424;
    UINT colorWidth = 1920, colorHeight = 1080;

    NUI_FUSION_IMAGE_FRAME *colorImage = nullptr;

    NuiFusionCreateImageFrame(NUI_FUSION_IMAGE_TYPE_COLOR, colorWidth, colorHeight, &cameraParameters, &colorImage);

    return 0;
```

}

the code literally does nothing but calling NuiFusionCreateImageFrame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that i copied the `Kinect20.fusion.dll` from `$(KINECTSDK20_DIR)\bin` to `$(OutDir)`, which is a x64 version.

The correct one is in `$(KINECTSDK20_DIR)\Redist\Fusion\x86`. Use this one and problem solved.